# Enable compiz window grid with visual effects set to none. Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager, compiz

I have to disable "Visual Effects" (system -> preferences-> appearance -> visual effects -> none) because I get a terrible flicker/blinking when it is enabled, but I'd really like to use compiz window grid shortcuts. They only work w/ visual effects set to "extra".

Is there any way to specifically enable compiz grid functionality without turning on everything else that seems to bog down the grapics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no...

No, you cannot enable the grid functionality of Compiz with the Visual Effects setting set to "none" as this actually disables Compiz for those devices that have no way to support running Compiz.

However, you might be able to get away with customizing the effects available with Compiz to be the minimum required to support the features you are looking for.

Install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package and run `ccsm` from the terminal.  This will allow detailed configuration of Compiz beyond just a few simple defaults.  I would caution you that some of these settings may or may not work for you as expected, as I have no idea what hardware you are using and what configuration you have.